# JQuery: Is it possible to select items close to checked checkboxes without iterating DOM-tree twice?

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way to select all items with a certain class close to a checked checkbox (same tr f.e.), **without iterating the tree twice?**

Comment: At least provide some basic markup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

`$('input:checked').closest('tr').find('.yourClass')`

Comment: $('input:checked').closest('.yourclass') is also possible.

Comment: Thanks the above worked like charm, needed to go through the tr tohough, Preben's didn't work for me.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts `$('input:checked').closest('.yourclass')` will only work if the `input` is within the `.yourclass`. `closest` searchs for the closest ancestor that matches.